# CMAKE: Configure/build a foreign package from your package

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, configure

Let say that your *CMake* C++ project depends on some external library such has *Google Benchmarks/Test*.

I know that I can independently configure and install the external library so that later when building my personal project I can access its *CMake* file which will nicely satisfy the dependency (It will nicely add its headers and library files)

My question is:

- Is it possible to directly *configure/build* this external library when configuring my project bypassing installing this external library?

Comment: Yes. Is it a good idea? Well, probably when you start to do this, your life will be much simpler if you use a dependency manager to manage the dependencies. vcpkg, conan.io, …

Comment: @spectras yeah I agree. Unfortunately, I cannot really do it in my specific case, the only help with dependencies I can use is CMake

Comment: For these who's boring to just build, there is a https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html module to bring ~problems~ fun to their life :)

Comment: You have my sympathy. Then ExternalProject that zaufi linked is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Have a look at https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html

This is exactly what I use for [fetching GTest](https://github.com/VeriBlock/alt-integration-cpp/blob/master/cmake/gtest.cmake).

Idea is simple - FetchContent will clone a repo for you, then you do `add_subdirectory` into that repo, and you can manage all subproject details (assuming project uses CMake and is written properly).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [`ExternalProject`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) which is even better than `FetchContent` if you want to build that you've fetched after.